# What datatype to choose for a dungeon map

Tags: haskell, data-structures

As part of a coding challenge I have to implement a dungeon map.

I have already designed it using `Data.Map` as a design choice because printing the map was not required and sometimes I had to update an map tile, e.g. when an obstacle was destroyed.

```
type Dungeon = Map Pos Tile

type Pos = (Int,Int) -- cartesian coordinates
data Tile = Wall | Destroyable | ...
```

But what if I had to print it too - then I would have to use something like 
`elaboratePrint . sort $ fromList dungeon` where `elaboratePrint` takes care of the linebreaks and makes nice unicode symbols from the tileset.

Another choice I considered would be a nested list

```
type Dungeon = [[Tile]]
```

This would have the disadvantage, that it is hard to update a single element in such a data structure. But printing then would be a simple one liner `unlines . map show`.

Another structure I considered was `Array`, but as I am not used to arrays a short glance at the hackage docs - i only found a map function that operated on indexes and one that worked on elements, unless one is willing to work with mutable arrays updating one element is not easy at first glance. And printing an array is also not clear how to do that fast and easily.

So now my question - is there a better data structure for representing a dungeon map that has the property of easy printing and easy updating single elements.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what worries you about printing a `Map`?

Comment: How many of your tile types are mutable?  There may be other options than updating the main data strucutre.  For instance, if destroyable obstacles are the only mutable tiles, you could maintain a list of the co-ordinates of destroyed tiles and check it when ever you interact with a destroyed tile.  Where destroyables are a small percentage of the overall map, that could be a win.  You could then choose the right moment to rebuild the map using that list to place plain tiles where obstacles have been destroyed, reducing the list to `[]`.  That moment might be when the list becomes too big...

Comment: Are all your maps completely square/rectangular, using every tile?

Comment: Sorry for answering this late, but I was busy. @DanielWagner I wonder if it is efficient to use `fromMap`, `sort` (as one cannot guarantee the order of keys) and grouping the keys and then get rid of the keys and print the result of this chain. @itsbruce yes I have rectangular maps.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am especially worried about the `sort`-part in this procedure as I don't know how long it takes.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe `Data.Map` offers [`toAscList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:toAscList), so you shouldn't need to sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about an `Array`? Haskell has real, 2-d arrays.

```
import Data.Array.IArray -- Immutable Arrays
```

Now an `Array` is indexed by any `Ix a => a`. And luckily, there is an instance `(Ix a, Ix b) => Ix (a, b)`. So we can have

```
 type Dungeon = Array (Integer, Integer) Tile
```

Now you construct one of these with any of several functions, the simplest to use being

```
array :: Ix i => (i, i) -> [(i, a)] -> Array i a
```

So for you,

```
startDungeon = array ( (0, 0), (100, 100) )
              [ ( (x, y), Empty ) | x <- [0..100], y <- [0..100]]
```

And just substitute `100` and `Empty` for the appropriate values.

If speed becomes a concern, then it's a simple fix to use [MArray](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.1/Data-Array-MArray-Safe.html) and `ST`. I'd suggest not switching unless speed is actually a real concern here.

To address the pretty printing

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

pretty :: Array (Integer, Integer) Tile -> String
pretty = unlines . map show . groupBy ((==) `on` snd.fst) . assoc
```

And `map show` can be turned in to however you want to format `[Tile]` into a row. If you decide that you really want these to be printed in an awesome and efficient manner (Console game maybe) you should look at a proper pretty printing library, like [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.1/Data-Array-MArray-Safe.html) one.

Comment: I had my look at `IArray`, but how do I get my array updated and printed?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm considering the fact that Array's have better safety guarentees about how always containing a certain number of elements and such. This is difficult to achieve with `[[Tile]]`

Comment: Plus they can be switched to using `ST` or `MArray`s relatively painlessly if speed is a problem

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Updated for printing, updating is `(\\)`, `ixmap` but, I'd suggest looking at `lens`. It's pretty awesome for this sorta stuff.

Comment: @jozefg I have only worked with Control.Lens - is there a easy way to make lens work with arrays, that would be great; I fully agree that `lens` is awesome.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Yep, Control.Lens.At

Comment: @jozefg I will definitely have a look at it `Control.Lens` is one of the bestest libraries out there!

Answer (score 3):

First — tree-likes such as `Data.Map` and lists remain the natural data structures for functional languages. `Map` is a bit of an overkill structure-wise if you only need rectangular maps, but `[[Tile]]` may actually be pretty fine. It has `O(√n)` for both random-access and updates, that's not too bad.

In particular, it's *better than pure-functional updates of a 2D array (`O(n)`)*! So if you need really good performance, there's no way around using *mutable* arrays. Which isn't necessarily bad though, after all a game is intrinsically concerned with IO and state. What *is* good about `Data.Array`, as noted by jozefg, is the ability to use tuples as `Ix` indexes, so I would go with [`MArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html).

Printing is easy with arrays. You probably only need rectangular *parts* of the whole map, so I'd just extract such slices with a simple list comprehension

```
[ [ arrayMap ! (x,y) | x<-[21..38] ] | y<-[37..47] ]
```

You already know how to print lists.

Comment: where does one find the `O(??)` for different structure properties, I often do not find those numbers, do I have to read the sources for each libraries?

Comment: You may need to deduce those yourself. A list of length _m_ has of course _O_ (_m_) on random-access. A 2D list with _n_ cells is a list of _√n_ rows with _√n_ elements each, so you get _O_ (_√n_ + _√n_) = _O_ (_√n_).